# should I use Django Groups or a simple model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to figure out which path to take to solve a problem.

Many-to-one  OR Django Groups?

I have a cat model and now I want to associate any new cats entered into my app with cat litters. (think new kittens)

I've been reading about Django Groups but only see this associated with the User model. Can Django Groups be used for any models I create? Is that the best path to get to what I want or should I just rely on a regular Many-to-One model relationship and build out regular models that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Groups: A generic way of applying labels and permissions to more than one user.**

In your case I would use,

**one to many**: assuming each kitten belongs to one cat.

**many to many**: if you link kitten to utmost two cats.

You should use groups for user authentication things, like admin group or specific user group and assign permission or rights to specific groups.

**So use accordingly.**

[more info on user authentication and groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/)

Comment: THANK YOU....this is exactly what I need (from a community of experienced developers). A concise kind bit of guidence from a developer more experienced on this topic. thank you again. I'll stick with my One-to-Many that I've built out then.

Comment: I still don't get it. Say you have something like an `Organization` model. From my understanding, you could just do 2 M2M relationships for things like `members` and `admins`. But would it be **better** to create groups for this, like `OrganizationAdmins` or `OrganizationMembers` or doing it the M2M way?